# java.io.FileNotFoundException The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, io, file-handling

I have a timer set to invoke a class that contains pdf generating codes.I have set the file path where it needs to be saved..but it is showing exception as java.io.FileNotFoundException : D:\ (The system cannot find the path specified) .I dont know where is the mistake..

Here is my code..

```
try {

        OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("D://"));
        Document document = new Document();
         //PDF generating code..     
        document.add(list);            //In the new page we are going to add list
        document.close();

        file.close();

        System.out.println("Pdf created successfully..");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: where is file name?? (new File("D://")) should have file name too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not provided the file name so you get that exception,use below code

```
  OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("D://timer.pdf"));
```

See the doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Answer (score 3):

You should provide a valid file name. You just can't provide the directory name alone, which is why you get the `FileNotFoundException`.

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("D://someFile.txt"));
```